# Wicket 7 --- Time out behaviour

Tags: wicket

i have just migrated from wicket 6.20 to 7.00.

And i notice that after time out occurred, it didn't redirect to Page i defined in **getApplicationSettings().setPageExpiredErrorPage(TimeOutPage.class);**

It just stuck at the page, where user has the last interaction with.

And for **ajax** component interaction, it will throw this exception :

**java.io.IOException: File name too long**

```
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:172)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource.getAlias(FileResource.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$ApproveNonExistentDirectoryAliases.check(ContextHandler.java:2595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.getResource(ContextHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.getResource(WebAppContext.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext$Context.getResource(WebAppContext.java:1395)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.getResourceAsStream(ContextHandler.java:1881)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.fallback(WicketServlet.java:233)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:139)
```

From the wicket previous version (6.20), it would redirect user to the TimeOut page, if user interacted with any component (ajax or non ajax).

Did i miss some configuration for this new version (7.00) ?

Please kindly advise.

regards.

Comment: Try switching to WicketFilter, that's the recommended setup for Wicket applications.

Comment: @svenmeier,  I integrated it with spring, so i have to use WicketServlet ===> org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory

Answer (score 0):

Try with `app.getPageSettings().setRecreateBookmarkablePagesAfterExpiry(false)`.

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/82f75959e61def603255eb3204e1706eb97bde0e/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/settings/PageSettings.java#L125

Comment: i have tried your suggestion, but it still have the same result after timeout.

Comment: Currently, I am using html tags **meta http-equiv="refresh"** to refresh every x seconds, and 'x' is the timeout second i defined in web.xml. This way it will redirect user to Resource Not found Page. Is the version 7 has different approach for timeout ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, i use the spring security feature **session-management**.

The 'timeout' and 'resource not found' is working perfectly.

Thanks.